# How to print an exception under rspec execution log and rails console?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, capybara, rspec-rails

When Letter Opener email is triggered, it get printed into `test.log`.

I need it to print it under `console log`.

When `Feature spec` is running and if exception is occurred, it should get printed into `server log` on terminal.

How to inspect the exception when email is triggered in `letter_opener_email` configuration?

As using `puts`, it can get printed, but where to write `puts` ?

using -

```
  ruby 1.9.3p0
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1.beta1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'letter_opener', '1.4.1'
```

Spec execution is done as -

```
rspec spec/features/user_spec.rb -fd --out log.txt
```

*Requirement*: when exception occurs, then it should get printed in Spec execution log(log.txt)

In my case, when exception occurs, it get saved into `/letter_opener` folder in html format.

I want to print that exception in `log.txt` in such a way that as it displays in browser(without displaying html, css tags).

letter_opener_files = Dir["#{Rails.root}/tmp/letter_opener/*/*"]

`letter_opener_files.sample` is as below :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">    
      <title> (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid) "OCIError: ORA-01722: invalid number: SELECT SUM(\"CASH_BOOK\".\"DEBIT\") AS sum_id FR...</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="message_headers">
        <dl>
          <dt>From:</dt>
          <dd>#&lt;Mail::Field:0x0000001dae4cb0&gt;</dd>          
            <dt>Subject:</dt>
            <dd><strong> (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid) "OCIError: ORA-01722: invalid number: SELECT SUM(\"CASH_BOOK\".\"DEBIT\") AS sum_id FR...</strong></dd>
        </dl>
      </div>
        <p id="message_body">An ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid occurred in background at 2018-02-14 20:15:29 +1300 :
  OCIError: ORA-01722: 
  stmt.c:253:in oci8lib_191.so

  -------------------------------
Backtrace:
-------------------------------

  stmt.c:253:in oci8lib_191.so
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ruby-oci8-2.1.2/lib/oci8/oci8.rb:474:in `exec'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_oci_connection.rb:143:in `exec
  </p>
```

I have tried below solution which is working, but mail get printed(with tags which is not required) in console only, not in `log.txt`

```
describe 'User' do

  after(:each) do
    page = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(File.read(letter_opener_files.sample))
    puts "Exception Occurred - #{page.css('p')}"
  end

  it 'should not have any exception' do
    create(:user)
  end

end
```

Got Output as below :

```
1.9.3-p0 :347 >puts "Exception Occurred - #{page.css('p')}"

Exception Occurred - <p id="message_body">An ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid occurred in background at 2018-02-14 20:15:29 +1300 :

  OCIError: ORA-01722: invalid number:
  stmt.c:253:in oci8lib_191.so

  -------------------------------
Backtrace:
-------------------------------

  stmt.c:253:in oci8lib_191.so
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ruby-oci8-2.1.2/lib/oci8/oci8.rb:474:in `exec'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_oci_connection.rb:143:in `exec'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_adapter.rb:627:in `block in exec_query'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:245:in `block in log'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.1.6/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:240:in `log'
</p>
```

*Expecting Output(in `log.txt` & console)* -

```
Exception Occurred - An ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid occurred in background at 2018-02-14 20:15:29 +1300 :

  OCIError: ORA-01722: invalid number:
  stmt.c:253:in oci8lib_191.so

  -------------------------------
Backtrace:
-------------------------------

  stmt.c:253:in oci8lib_191.so
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ruby-oci8-2.1.2/lib/oci8/oci8.rb:474:in `exec'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_oci_connection.rb:143:in `exec'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_adapter.rb:627:in `block in exec_query'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:245:in `block in log'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.1.6/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:240:in `log'
```

Please advise if there is any better way to do this and how to print exception under `log.txt`?

Comment: It sounds like you've configured something else (exception_notifier maybe) to email all exceptions.  You should just need to turn that off in the `test` environment. All of these gems are REALLY old though, you might want to look at upgrading at some point.

Comment: Yes, but at this point I need to continue with exception_notifier.

Comment: ok, but you don’t need to use it in the test environment

Comment: @Thomas, but it works fine for my requirement.

Comment: huh?  If it worked for you then why post this question?  exception_notifier is catching exceptions and mailing them into letter_opener - if you just disable exception_notifier in the test environment you’ll have the exception in you RSpec log just like you want

Comment: Are you sure? what if exception occurs in background and rspec never fails?

Comment: In what background? Any background jobs should be run online in test mode, or completion explicitly waited for in your tests. Disabling exception_notifier in test mode doesn’t stop exceptions from being reported, just from being emailed (which you shouldn’t want when running tests anyway)